# How to get exact url in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

When i am trying to redirect using Action Link, I am getting some extra texts in url.

This is url : localhost:51587/Admin/Performance .

When i using action link : localhost:51587/Admin/Performance?Length=5 .

I don't know where is am getting that ?Length=5. Please help me to resolve this problem.

This is my Action Link code:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Click here", "Performance", "DailyReport")
```

Comment: Can you show the action link to Performance action in Admin controller. It seems like you have posted the Html.ActionLink call for another method.

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned wrong one..Now i changed it..please check it out now

Comment: It seems that you are calling "Admin" controller rather than the "DailyReport" controller you are calling from your action link.